# For Loop to call multiple variables from properties file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a properties file which I call inside my Jenkins Pipeline Script to get multiple variables.

```
BuildCounter = n
BuildName1 = Name 1
BuildName2 = Name 2
   ...
Buildnamen = Name n
```

I call my properties file with: `def props = readProperties file: Path`

Now I want to create a loop to print all my BuildNames

```
for (i = 0; i < BuildJobCounterInt; i++){
            tmp = 'BuildName' + i+1
            println props.tmp
}
```

But of course this is not working. ne last println call is searching for a variable called `tmp` in my properties file. Is there a way to perform this or am I completely wrong?

EDIT:

This is my .properties file:

```
BuildJobCounter = 1
BuildName1 = 'Win32'
BuildPath1 = '_Build/MBE3_Win32'
BuildName2 = 'empty'
BuildPath2 = 'empty'

TestJobCounter = '0'
TestName1 = 'empty'
TestPath1 = 'empty'
TestName2 = 'empty'
TestPath2 = 'empty'
```

In my Jenkins pipeline I want to have the possibility to check the ammount of Build/TestJobs and automatically calle the Jobs (each BuildName and BuildPath is a Freestyle Job) To call all these Job I thought of calling the variables inside a for loop. So for every `i`step I have the Name/Path pair.

Comment: like this? `props.each{ k,v -> println "$k = $v" }`

Comment: Generally yes, Thank you but I also need the variables which start with `BuildName` followed by a number. There are some other vars which are needed later.

Comment: @daggett, that should be an answer, I believe.

Comment: I tried the for loop to perform different actions for each individual variable. But I cant figure it out. maybe I am completetly wrong :D

Comment: @RodKimble, any example to what you say in your comment?

Comment: @RodKimble, do you want to try `println props[tmp]` or `println props."$tmp"`?

Comment: I added some more Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

Change from:

```
println props.tmp
```

To:

```
println props[tmp]
```

or

```
println props."$tmp"
```

**EDIT : based on OP comment**

change from:

```
tmp = 'BuildName' + i+1
```

To:

```
def tmp = "BuildName${(i+1).toString()}"
```

Comment: Not working. The outpu is `null` (I think because it searches for `props.tmp`

Comment: @RodKimble, there is another change which I just fixed under `EDIT`. Would you please give it a try along with previous change?

Comment: Thank you. Works fine ;)

Comment: @RodKimble, thank you for your patience and glad to know that it helped.